# Getting a drop down box value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get the value currently selected and I simply want to alert it.

I current have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert(forms.elements('sets').value);

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<select name="sets">
  <option value="1">1 Set</option>
  <option value="2">2 Sets</option>
  <option value="F">3 Sets</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form without ID:

`var val = document.forms[0].sets.value` - first form on the page

Named form (form name="myForm") - will not validate in some doctypes:

`var val = document.myForm.sets.value;`

Form with ID (form id="myForm"):

`var val = document.getElementById("myForm").sets.value;`

Long version:

`var sets = document.myForm.sets;`
`var val = sets.options[sets.selectedIndex].value;`

Without the form - no ID on the select:

`var val = document.getElementsByName("sets")[0].value;` - first field with that name on the page

With ID on the select (select id="sets")

`var val = document.getElementById("sets").value;`

---

`alert(val);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
<select name="sets">
  <option value="1">1 Set</option>
  <option value="2">2 Sets</option>
  <option value="F">3 Sets</option>
</select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementsByName('sets')[0];
    alert(select.value);
</script>
```